# Question on CountDown Timer Java, Android

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm studying Java+Android now and I have the following example of a code, that is working fine.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        new CountDownTimer(10000,1000){
            public void onTick(long msUntillDone){
                Log.i("Seconds left",String.valueOf(msUntillDone/1000));
            }

            public void onFinish(){
                Log.i("Finished","We are done!");
            }
        }.start();

    }
}
```

The question that I have is following. In the onTick function there is msUntillDone variable that I pass to it, and it gets that its 10000. But where does it get that from the new CountDownTimer, I mean how does it know it's value if I don't explicitly assign this name to 10000 value in main method arguments?

I hope you understand my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CountDownTimer(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval)`

The `CountDownTimer` schedules a countdown until a time in the future, with regular notifications on intervals along the way.

It means that the `onTick()` method is periodically called, every `countDownInterval` milliseconds (more and less). It is a mandatory parameter or course

You can consider the `CountDownTimer` as a counter, decreasing from `millisInFuture` to 0 and which warning the caller about the progress every `countDownInterval` milliseconds.

If you're interested by how it works under the hood, you can check the implementation : https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/java/android/os/CountDownTimer.java;l=44?q=CountDownTimer&sq=

Comment: I understand that. The question is following. How public void onTick(long msUntillDone) understands that it's value is  from new CountDownTimer(10000,1000) and is 10000. I don't declare it like new CountDownTimer(long msUntillDone=10000,1000).

And more than that, the long msUntillDone is decreasing every second, by one second. 10000,9000,8000 etc.

I'm used to PHP and there you need to do smth like a for loop to do that, and there you declare the variables that you will use. Why I don't declare it in here?

Comment: I mean how "long msUntillDone" assigns itself to CountDownTimer(long millisInFuture)?